# Displaying Hierarchical Search Results with State, City, and Community Name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a search functionality where users can search for specific towns. However, the expected output should display the state, city, and town in a hierarchical manner.

Current Behavior:
When I typed "town" in the search input field, the result displayed is only "Westmont Town Court".
[image]

Expected Behavior:
The search result should display in the following hierarchical format:

California
↳ Escondido
↳ Westmont Town Court

The display should resemble the format used in our model site's search feature: first the state, followed by an arrow, then the city, another arrow, and finally the community name.
[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Find a Community Near You" id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        <div id="down" class="down">
            <ul class="state">
                <!-- California -->
                <li data-state="California">
                    <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california">California</a>
                    <ul class="city">
                        <!-- San Diego -->
                        <li data-city="San Diego">
                            <a href="https://myweb.com/our- communities/california/san-diego">San Diego</a>
                            <ul class="community">
                                <li><a href="https://myweb.com/our-communities/california/san-diego/westmont-of-carmel-valley/">Westmont of Carmel Valley</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                         

<script>
    function filterFunction() {
        let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        let div = document.getElementById("down");

        // Initially, hide everything
        let allItems = div.querySelectorAll("li");
        allItems.forEach(item => item.style.display = "none");

        // Search communities
        let communities = div.querySelectorAll(".community > li");
        for (let community of communities) {
            if (community.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
                // If it matches, display the community
                community.style.display = "";

                // Find and display the parent city
                let cityElement = community.closest('[data-city]');
                if (cityElement) {
                    cityElement.style.display = "";
                }

                // Find and display the parent state
                let stateElement = community.closest('[data-state]');
                if (stateElement) {
                    stateElement.style.display = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please include your code here as a minimal reproducible example - whittle it down to the pieces necessary to show your problem. Links can break and are then no help to future readers.

Comment: While the code seems to be fetching the correct pieces, I think the `#down` selector having `display:none;` is preventing anything from showing. You may need to remove that and set the `display:none;` on your cities and states to start with, then update when matches are found. I'd use a class to show/hide those.

Comment: Thank you, @mykaf for your suggestion and input. I will test that out and also take note of your suggestion.

Comment: I think you also need to be very consistent with your `data-` attributes. For example, I'm seeing `<li data-city="Escondido">...`, but Goleta doesn't have the `data-city` attribute, it's just `<li>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding the entire parent div `#down` means that the child elements won't show, even if they are individually set to display. I've added more consistent `data-city` and `data-state` attributes, and used a `hidden` class to show and hide the cities and states.

```js
function hideAll() {
document.querySelectorAll(".city li[data-city],.state li[data-state]").forEach(cs => cs.classList.add("hidden"));
}
function filterFunction() {
        let input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        let div = document.getElementById("down");

        // Initially, hide everything
        hideAll();
        //let allItems = div.querySelectorAll("li");

        // Search communities
        let communities = div.querySelectorAll(".community > li");
        for (let community of communities) {
            if (community.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)) {
                // If it matches, display the community

                // Find and display the parent city
                let cityElement = community.closest('[data-city]');
                if (cityElement) {
                    cityElement.classList.remove("hidden")
                }

                // Find and display the parent state
                let stateElement = community.closest('[data-state]');
                if (stateElement) {
                    stateElement.classList.remove("hidden")
                }
            }
        }
    }
   hideAll();
```

```css
        .city li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1px;
}

.city li a {
    display: inline-block; /* This might help with the negative margin application */
    margin-left: -13px; /* Increase the negative margin */
}

.city li a::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/arrow.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 60%;
    width: 20.4px;
    height: 20.4px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


        /* explore our communities search bar css*/

    #myInput {
    background-image: url('https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/search.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 10px center; 
    background-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 40px; /* Adjust the padding depending on the size of the icon */
    transition: background 0.4s;
    padding:12px 15px;
}

/* Optionally: Change the icon or its position when the input field is focused */
#myInput:focus {
    background-position: right 40px center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#down {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 240px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
#down ul{
    margin: 0em 0 0em 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;

}

/* #down {
    display: none;
} */
.hidden {display:none;}


        
        
/* our communities css*/
#showmore
{display: none;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#c-button {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #2F6130;
    border-color: #2F6130;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#c-button a{
    color:#fff;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
#c-button {  
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}}

#show{
text-decoration:underline; 
cursor: pointer;
color: #000;

}


.cta-community a {
    display: block;
    color:#000;
    
}
.elementor-cta__content, .elementor-cta__content-item .cta-community {
    position: relative;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #fff;
    display: block !important;
}

h3.elementor-cta__title.elementor-cta__content-item.elementor-content-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


ul.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #2f6130 !important;
}
ul.sub-menu a {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="dropdown">
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Find a Community Near You" id="myInput" onchange="filterFunction()">
            <div id="down" class="down">
                <ul class="state">
                    <!-- California -->
                    <li data-state="California">
                        <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california">California</a>
                        <ul class="city">
                            <!-- San Diego -->
                            <li data-city="San Diego">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/san-diego">San Diego</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/san-diego/westmont-of-carmel-valley/">Westmont of Carmel Valley</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Culver City -->
                            <li data-city="Culver City">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/culver-city">Culver City</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/culver-city/westmont-of-culver-city/">Westmont of Culver City</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Cypress -->
                            <li data-city="Cypress">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/cypress">Cypress</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/cypress/westmont-of-cypress/">Westmont of Cypress</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Encinitas -->
                            <li data-city="Encinitas">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/encinitas">Encinitas</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/encinitas/westmont-of-encinitas/">Westmont of Encinitas</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- La Mesa -->
                            <li data-city="La Mesa">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/la-mesa">La Mesa</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/la-mesa/westmont-of-la-mesa/">Westmont of La Mesa</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Riverside -->
                            <li data-city="Riverside">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/riverside">Riverside</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/riverside/westmont-of-riverside/">Westmont of Riverside</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/riverside/westmont-village-homes/">Westmont Village Homes</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Chula Vista -->
                            <li data-city="Chula Vista">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/chula-vista">Chula Vista</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/chula-vista/westmont-at-san-miguel-ranch/">Westmont at San Miguel Ranch</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Escondido -->
                            <li data-city="Escondido">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/escondido">Escondido</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li data-community="Westmont Town Court"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/escondido/westmont-town-court/">Westmont Town Court</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Central California Cities... -->
                            <!-- Goleta -->
                            <li data-city="Goleta">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/goleta">Goleta</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/goleta/mariposa-at-ellwood-shores/">Mariposa at Ellwood Shores</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Fresno -->
                            <li data-city="Fresno">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/fresno">Fresno</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/communities/central-california/fresno/westmont-of-fresno/">Westmont of Fresno</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Nipomo -->
                            <li data-city="Nipomo">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/nipomo">Nipomo</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/nipomo/the-oaks-at-nipomo/">The Oaks at Nipomo</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Paso Robles -->
                            <li data-city="Paso Robles">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/paso-robles/">Paso Robles</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/paso-robles/the-oaks-at-paso-robles/">The Oaks at Paso Robles</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Northern California Cities... -->
                            <!-- Brentwood -->
                            <li data-city="Brentwood">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/brentwood/">Brentwood</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/brentwood/westmont-of-brentwood/">Westmont of Brentwood</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Morgan Hill -->
                            <li data-city="Morgan Hill">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/morgan-hill">Morgan Hill</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/morgan-hill/westmont-of-morgan-hill/">Westmont of Morgan Hill</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Milpitas -->
                            <li data-city="Milpitas">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/milpitas">Milpitas</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/milpitas/westmont-of-milpitas/">Westmont of Milpitas</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Pinole -->
                            <li data-city="Pinole">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/pinole">Pinole</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/pinole/westmont-of-pinole/">Westmont of Pinole</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Chico -->
                            <li data-city="Chico">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/chico">Chico</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/chico/the-inn-at-the-terraces/">The Inn at the Terraces</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/california/chico/the-lodge-at-the-terraces/">The Lodge at the Terraces</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul> <!-- End of California cities -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- Oregon -->
                    <li data-state="Oregon">
                        <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/oregon">Oregon</a>
                        <ul class="city">
                            <!-- Lincoln City -->
                            <li data-city="Lincoln City">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/oregon/lincoln-city">Lincoln City</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/oregon/lincoln-city/lakeview-senior-living/">Lakeview Senior Living</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Newport -->
                            <li data-city="Newport">
                                <a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/oregon/newport">Newport</a>
                                <ul class="community">
                                    <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/our-communities/oregon/newport/oceanview-senior-living/">Oceanview Senior Living</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul> <!-- End of Oregon cities -->
                    </li>
                </ul> <!-- End of state list -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Much obliged! I will test this out ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, @mykaf. The original behavior we want to maintain is that once the mouse cursor is placed in the input text field, the default results should be displayed. As the user types, the relevant results should be updated in real-time, showcasing the hierarchical search results, including State, City, and Community Name.

Comment: I had changed the event listener to "change", but you can continue using your "keyup" if that's your desired outcome.

Comment: Much obliged to you, @mykaf!